# How to add background image to only selected page in ktinter of Python?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to add a "page under construction" png file to only 1 of the 3 pages under my release menu which has "release 1", "release 2", and "release 3".

```
{def underConstruction():
    my_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('c/path/to/my/png/file')
    my_label = Label(image=my_img)
    my_label.pac()
    print "I am adding the png file here."}
```

my calling statement is:
{subMenu.add_command(Label="Release 1...", command = underConstruction.}
the problem is only the print statement gets executed. It did not pull in the png file. What went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`my_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('c/path/to/my/png/file')` is missing a paren at the end.

`my_label.pac()` should be `my_label.pack()`

Your calling statement should have a lowercase `label =`  instead of `Label =` .

If this code isn't throwing any errors, you might want to figure out what your error handling is doing to prevent it from doing that.